# iOS: Custom back button doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use FlatUIKit in my project. I have a custom Back button defined like this:

```
    [UIBarButtonItem configureFlatButtonsWithColor:[UIColor peterRiverColor]
                              highlightedColor:[UIColor belizeHoleColor]
                                  cornerRadius:3
                               whenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                             target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(clickBack)];
```

And here is my clickBack

```
 -(void)clickBack{
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers     objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-1] animated:YES];

}
```

The button appears as I want it to but that's it. If I click on it, nothing happens.

Any idea what I did wrong? I'm pretty new to this and never replaced a back button.

Comment: `objectAtIndex:count-1` is going to return the current view controller, not the previous.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint inside clickBack method? is your code reaching that part? Or write an NSLog over there to see if prints...

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried to set it to -2 then but it crashed the app.

Comment: I checked my code Emilio, it does get to that part.

Comment: can you print out `self.navigationController`, is it nil? are you pushing the view controller onto the stack or are you presenting the view controller modally?

Comment: Should I add NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController); to clickBack? I'm presenting it modally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just mentioned in one of your comments that you presented the view controller modally, that's different. You'll want to release the modal view controller. Try this:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The pop method is only going to work if the view you are releasing was pushed onto the navigation controller.

Here's a link to a modal view controller example.

http://timneill.net/2010/09/modal-view-controller-example-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

use this code in clickBack method

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already actually but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually have a previous view controller to go back to.

Comment: Well I do. Is it because I introduced the new view controller modally? If I choose push, the app just crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIBarButtonItem configureFlatButtonsWithColor:[UIColor peterRiverColor]
                              highlightedColor:[UIColor belizeHoleColor]
                                  cornerRadius:3
                               whenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                             target:self
                                                                            action:@selector(clickBack)];


 -(void)clickBack
{

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

copy and paste this code as it is.